# 2011Chevy Equinox the automatic Temperature control quit functioning! The ac and heat quit ,I’m manually making the heater work and ac quit!

Tags: ac, heater

2011 Chevy Equinox lt 2.4 FWD HVAC ! The temperature control switch quit functioning making it heat only! The ac completely quit. I make the heater work manually!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does your auto climate control allow over riding it to manually use ac or heat? Without more info, this can be; a climate control head,  hvac actuator, loss of refrigerant or blown fuse problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.